What are the best DRY practices for terragrunt live with environments and regions?
I have the following folders and files structure:
├── live
│   └── environments
│       └── alpha
│           ├── control-plane
│           ├── env.hcl
│           ├── global
│           └── regional
│               ├── eu-central-1
│               │   ├── networking
│               │   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│               │   └── region.hcl
│               └── us-west-2
│                   ├── networking
│                   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│                   └── region.hcl
├── provider.tf
├── terraform.tfstate
└── terragrunt.hcl

Where:

region.hcl declares

locals {
  region = reverse(split("/", get_terragrunt_dir()))[0]
}


env.hcl declares

locals {
  environment = reverse(split("/", get_terragrunt_dir()))[0]
}

This is basically allowing me to replicate and isolate modules in distinct regions, which was harder with terraform some versions ago but now doable with tofu 1.8
So far I have the following concerns, goals to achive:

Is there a way to avoid having to manually replicate <region>/<modules/terragrunt.hcl> files?
Could I achieve some sort of files and folder templating?
How would dynamic provider with upcoming tofu 1.9 help me with current setup, where I could have a placeholder env and base region folder and iterate passing a var for its region?
How much distinct is this setup from the Keep your Architecture DRY guide where an _env folder is recommended?

My needs are for multiple apps that have pretty much same design. These apps represent countries, each would have 2 distinct regions, and each need up to 5-8 regional modules.
If I have 8 countries, I have up 8 countries X 2 regions X 8 permutations which means 128 hcl files to write. I definitely care to go DRY or just make sure I get a chance on more tooling/templating.

This is a very broad question, and I wouldn't expect any concrete answers. There are many ways to tackle multi-region / multi-backend configurations, and which is best not only depends on the environment but also your preferences for organization. For example, I use a linker script that looks for "linkable" directories and builds hundreds of softlinks where they are needed in states. Many would bristle at this just reading it, but it works in this context.

Hello @theherk well your linker may work, if you don't mind, I'd love to see it in an answer

It sounds like your use case is a good candidate for Terragrunt Stacks, which is currently in RFC mode. At a high-level, one key design point of Terragrunt is that it drives you to work with "small chunks" of infrastructure. But when you have a common reusable pattern as you have here, most users copy/paste them today, and Terragrunt Stacks will be a way to define your pattern once and instantiate it many times.

diegoaguilar and I chatted over in the OpenTofu Community Slack about this.
This is some content that I shared with him there:
Have you had a chance to see this? https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/3313
I think that RFC is ultimately the solution you're hoping for, and would love if you gave it a reaction with a thumbs up or something.
In the short term, I would investigate these two capabilities:
https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/catalog/
https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/scaffold/
Which can help with templating.
The point of a _env folder is to help with reducing repetition inside terragrunt.hcl files. If you find that you have a lot of content repeated in multiple terragrunt.hcl files, you can reduce that repetition via include configuration blocks.
You can see an example of that here:
https://github.com/yhakbar/terragrunt-3313-stacks-walkthrough/tree/main/walkthrough/03-includes-dependencies
Hopefully this helps out some other folks too!

It sounds like you're looking for a way to generate code. I've found that Terramate is the best tool right now to be able to do this. It takes a bit of a paradigm shift, but you can code module definitions in *.tm.hcl files like:
generate_hcl "_terramate_generated_main.tf" {
  inherit = true

  condition = tm_contains(terramate.stack.tags, "networking")

  content {
    module "networking" {
      source = tm_format("git@github.com:<your org>/<your repo>.git//modules/networking?ref=%s", global.module.version.networking)         
      environment_short = global.environment_short
      <other attributes here

      providers = {
        aws        = was
        aws.infra = aws.infra
      }
    }
  }
}

Then in your stack you can have module definitions like:
globals "module" "version" {
  networking = "0.1.0",
  <other modules here>
}

Furthermore, because of the way that the globals are composed, you can have global module overrides in environments so you can slow
